# Retrieving EC2 Instance RSA Fingerprint

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, winscp

I am trying to automate the complete process of initiating an EC2 instance and then performing some executions over it and then closing it. Everything is working fine except one problem.

I cant SSH into my EC2 instance. To SSH into the EC2 just created i need the RSA fingerprint of that particular instance, which is not available. Now i can extract the log by using aws cli but it is very complex to extract it from there, as the extracted file contain no new line character. Is there any direct command through which we can know what the fingerprint of EC2 Instance is, without logging in it ?

I am using winscp to log in to the system by following command

```
"open sftp://ec2-user@%varPublicIp% -timeout=120 -privatekey="D:\subham_ec2key\privateKey-us-west-1.ppk" -hostkey="<RSA FINGERPRINT>""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code snippet will solve the problem. The code snippet is for batch script.

```
aws ec2 get-console-output --output table --instance-id "i-256789"> InstanceId.txt
findstr "(RSA)" varInstanceId.txt>RSAFingerprint.txt
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%G in (RSAFingerprint.txt) do @echo %%G>RSAFingerprint.txt
for /f "delims=" %%G in (RSAFingerprint.txt) do set varRSAFingerprint=%%G
echo varRSAFingerprint: %varRSAFingerprint%
```

**Now lets understand the above code line by line**

```
aws ec2 get-console-output --output table --instance-id "i-256789"> InstanceId.txt
```

ec2 console output will provide the system log for the EC2 Instance. It is very essential to take the output in `table` format otherwise the json output doesn't provide any CRLF in the file making it impossible to extract the RSA Fingerprint.

```
findstr "(RSA)" varInstanceId.txt>RSAFingerprint.txt
```

finding `(RSA)` keyword from the syslog file generated, when it will find the `(RSA)` keyword on that file it will return the complete line containing the keyword and will put it into the `RSAFingerprint.txt`.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%G in (RSAFingerprint.txt) do @echo %%G>RSAFingerprint.txt
```

Above line will extract the fingerprint only from the line earlier extracted.

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in (RSAFingerprint.txt) do set varRSAFingerprint=%%G
```

above line will put the fingerprint in the variable `varRSAFingerprint`.